# Perl: Simple form submission causes URL to be appended to current URL

Tags: perl, cgi

So. I am new to perl. This simple script is just supposed to create a table with specified dimensions showing numbers, like in a times table. I'm trying to keep tabs on how many times the script is refreshed by recording it with the path info like so: script.cgi/1

except when it refreshes it does something like:
script.cgi (first time use)
script.cgi/1
script.cgi/1/script.cgi/2

why does this happen?

script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

BEGIN {
    $| = 1;
    open(STDERR,">&STDOUT");
    print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
}

print "<html>\n<head>\n<title>Homework 5</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n";
print "<h1>Homework 5B</h1>\n<hr />\n";
if(defined($ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'}))
{
    my %FORM;
    my $buffer = {};
    read(STDIN,$buffer,$ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
    my @pairs = split(/&/,$buffer);
    my $name=0; my $value=0;
    foreach my $pair (@pairs)
    {
        ($name,$value) = split(/=/,$pair);
        $FORM{$name} = $value;
    }
    if($ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'}>0)
    {
        my @table = [];
        my $var1 = $FORM{'rows'};
        my $var2 = $FORM{'columns'};
        if(
            (!($FORM{'rows'} =~ m/[^0-9]/)) 
            && (!($FORM{'columns'} =~ m/[^0-9]/)) 
            && (!($FORM{'inc'} =~ m/[^0-9]/)) 
            && (!($FORM{'start'} =~ m/[^0-9]/))
        )
        {
            my $place = $FORM{'start'};
            my $i=-1;
            while($i++ < $var1)
            {
                my $j=-1;
                $table[$i] = [];
                while($j++ < $var2)
                {
                    $table[$i][$j] = $place;
                    $place+=$FORM{'inc'};
                }
            }
        }
        print "<table border=1>\n";
        my $var =0; my $before = "<td>"; my $after = "</td>";
        for(my $i=0;$i<$FORM{'rows'};$i++)
        {
            $var = $i+1;
            print "<tr><td>Row $var:</td>\n";
            for(my $j=0;$j<$FORM{'columns'};$j++)
            {
                my $pr = $before.($table[$i][$j]).$after; 
                print $pr;
            }
            print "</tr>\n";
        }
        print "</table>\n";
        my $refreshed = 0;
        if(defined($ENV{'PATH_INFO'}))
        {
            my $tmp = split(/\//,$ENV{'PATH_INFO'});
            $refreshed = $tmp;
            if($refreshed==1)
            {
                print "<p>This page was refreshed by this script one time.</p>\n";
            }
            elsif($refreshed>1)
            {
                print "<p>This page was refreshed by this script $refreshed times</p>\n";
            }
        }
        my $path = "";
        my $next = $refreshed+1;
        if($next>1)
        {
            $path = "hw5B.cgi/".$next."/";
        }
        else
        {
            $path = "hw5B.cgi/1/";
        }
        print "<p>$path</p>\n";
        print "<form method=\"post\" action=\"$path\">\n";
        print "<span>Enter row number:<input type=\"text\" name=\"rows\" size=3 value=$FORM{'rows'} /></span><br />\n";
        print "<span>Enter columns number:<input type=\"text\" name=\"columns\" size=3 value=$FORM{'columns'} /></span><br />\n";
        print "<span>Enter starting number:<input type=\"text\" name=\"start\" size=3 value=$FORM{'start'} /></span><br />\n";
        print "<span>Enter increment:<input type=\"text\" name=\"inc\" size=3 value=$FORM{'inc'} /></span><br />\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "<form method=\"post\" action=\"hw5B.cgi\">\n";
        print "<span>Enter row number:<input type=\"text\" name=\"rows\" size=3 /></span><br />\n";
        print "<span>Enter columns number:<input type=\"text\" name=\"columns\" size=3 /></span><br />\n";
        print "<span>Enter starting number:<input type=\"text\" name=\"start\" size=3 /></span><br />\n";
        print "<span>Enter increment:<input type=\"text\" name=\"inc\" size=3 /></span><br />\n";
    }
}
else
{
    print "<form method=\"post\" action=\"hw5B.cgi\">\n";
    print "<span>Enter row number:<input type=\"text\" name=\"rows\" size=3 /></span><br />\n";
    print "<span>Enter columns number:<input type=\"text\" name=\"columns\" size=3 /></span><br />\n";
    print "<span>Enter starting number:<input type=\"text\" name=\"start\" size=3 /></span><br />\n";
    print "<span>Enter increment:<input type=\"text\" name=\"inc\" size=3 /></span><br />\n";
}
print "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\" />\n";
print "</form>\n</body>\n</html>\n";
```

Comment: Got a syntax error at line 69: Global symbol "$tmp3" requires explicit package name.  Probably want that to just be $tmp;

Comment: It's 2014. Why are you writing a web application using CGI? And why are you writing a CGI program without using CGI.pm? Where are you getting your advice from?

Comment: I ummm... am taking a class teaching outdated perl practices. I figure it won't be a waste if I learn the core perl functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a relative path in your post method.  Your server is therefore appending to your current path each time. You can put an absolute path instead which would alleviate the issue, or you can just include this counter as a cgi paramater instead of inside the path.

```
<input type="hidden" name="counter" value="$counter">
```

Also, to make your life easier, I'd suggest that you use an alternative double quote delimiter so that you don't have to escape all the double quotes in your html:

```
print qq{<form method="post" action="hw5B.cgi">\n};
```